# The meaning of the word (outstretch) or (stretched out)

Tags: meaning

I have been reading a book and these days I find this word many times. I couldn't find out the meaning of it. Could you please help me?

Comment: Um... do you mean "outstretched"? Have you looked at a dictionary? What don't you understand?

Comment: This is an example i found i dictionary (They ran towards each other with arms outstretched, )  thanks

Comment: ...and what does the dictionary definition say?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sentences

> They ran towards each other with arms outstretched,

and

> They ran towards each other with arms stretched out,

say the same thing.

If you know that "to stretch out one's arms" means to fix one's arms so as to be ready to hug someone else, then *ipso facto* you know the meaning of "arms outstretched". In other words, the two sentences mean the same thing.

In your example, the people running towards one another are excited or eager (or both) to embrace (or hug) each other.